# Is there a way to recover files in working directory overwritten by git checkout in sublime text 3?

Tags: git, sublimetext3

I am working in sublime text3 with git package installed. here is my scenario consider this example I did the following commits on Jan-31 on Feb-28 on Mar 31 then I did not commit for couple of months (apr and jun) at the end of june i don't know which command I ran within sublime git ( I guess checkout) and my latest local files are replaced with last git repo from Mar 31. It even deleted some files that i created after Mar 31 on my local drive. What can i do to revert those changes and get my latest local files back. I made some big time consuming changes that I can't afford to do again. Is there a way to recover local files that I created/changed after last commit?

I tried to do git reset but that didn't have any effect

Comment: You can recover any missing commits from `git reflog`, but since you did not had them committed, they are gone forever, unless you have some system recovery

Comment: what kind of recovery options do i have in sublime text 3. I tried using third party recovery programs but the content of recovered files are not what they were suppose to be. Doesn't git keep track of what it deleted in working directory and can recover those?

Comment: Did you add or stash these files?

Comment: No I did not. I did not do any git operations in last two months.

Comment: Git keeps history of only those files that you add to index, not all files

Comment: Sublime doesn't have any sort of file recovery on its own; unless you installed a third party package that tries to keep history, there is no functionality like that at your disposal. That said I would also expect that `git` would not overwrite a file without telling you and making you force it to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did not do any git operations in last two month

Then, beside a [file recovery tool](https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-file-recovery-software), check if you have a plugin like [Local history](https://github.com/vishr/local-history).
Only such a plugin would keep automatically a copy of modified files.

If not... again, a file recovery tool would be the last resort.